# Posts in two different columns Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I want the posts on the main page to be arranged in Bootstrap columns in this way:
[image]

I have this code, but instead of the first two posts, only one is displayed.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $count_one = 1; ?>
<?php $count_two = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if ($count_one % 5 == 1): ?>
        <div class="row one">
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content-one'); // For col-6 ?>
            <?php $count_one++; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($count_two % 3 == 0): ?>
            <div class="row two">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content-two'); // For col-4 ?>
        <?php $count_two++;
        if (($count_two % 3) == 0) { ?></div><!--row-->
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $count_one++; endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('We can&rsquo;t find what you&rsquo;re looking for.', THEME_SLUG); ?></p>
<?php endif;
if (($count_two % 3) == 1) { ?>
    </div><!--row-->
<?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please tell me where the error is.

Comment: If the issue is with a missing post within a row then the problem is in `template-parts/content-one`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. `template-parts/content-one` connects without errors. The problem is that the counter displays not two posts, but one.